# Get the latest 12 photos from Flickr public account

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an #images div that contain 12  tag, I want to fill these images with the latest 12 images from a Flickr account. What is the code I need for this?

Comment: You need to try some thing before coming to `SOF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need the flickr id for the username you want to retrieve the images from. You can find that using http://idgettr.com

You can then use that, along with the JSON format and a JASONP callback to construct an URL, which you then pass to a $.getJSON() jquery function.

an example taken from the book 'JavaScript & jQuery the missing manual' looks something like this

```
var flickrURL = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?ids=userId&format=json&jsoncallback=?"
$.getJSON(flickrURL, function(data){
//do something with returned data
});//end get
```

as Ummar suggested, you will need to make a bit more of an effort yourself... Try searching for 'add a flickr feed to your website' to find some useful tutorials, and go from there.